Lagrange multiplier for coupling flux across subdomains
I am solving two pdes:
(1) $\nabla\cdot(\kappa \nabla u)=0$ in $\Omega = \Omega_1\bigcup\Omega_2$
where $\Omega$ can be thought of as a unit square vertically divided into two equal halves.
(2) $\frac{\partial c}{\partial t}-\nabla\cdot(D\nabla c)=0$ in $\Omega_2$.
The first pde has Dirichlet boundary conditions at left and right vertical boundaries, and $\kappa\nabla u \cdot \pmb{n}=0$ on the horizontal boundaries.
The second pde has $D\nabla c \cdot \pmb{n}=0$ on $\partial \Omega_2\setminus \bigl( \partial\Omega_1\bigcup \partial\Omega_2\bigr)$ and $c(t=0)=c_0$.
I would like to solve the two pdes subject to the constraint that
$$\kappa\nabla u \cdot \pmb{n} - FD\nabla c \cdot \pmb{n} = 0\mathrm{\ on\ }\partial\Omega_1\bigcup \partial \Omega_2$$, so constraint at the vertical interface between the two subdomains.
I am using Lagrange multipliers to apply the constraint.
I have written the following energy functional for the two pdes
$$
\mathcal{J}(u, c) = \int_{\Omega}\frac{\kappa}{2}\vert \nabla u \vert^2\mathrm{dx} - \int_{\Gamma_{N_u}}g_0 u \mathrm{ds} + \int_{\Omega_2}(0.5c - c_0)c\mathrm{dx} -\Delta t\int_{\Omega_2}\frac{D}{2}\vert \nabla c \vert^2\mathrm{dx} + \Delta t\int_{\Gamma_{N_c}}g_2 c \mathrm{ds}
$$
I then added the Lagrange multiplier constraint to the functional to obtain:
$$
\mathcal{L}(u, c, \lambda) = \int_{\Omega}\frac{\kappa}{2}\vert \nabla u \vert^2\mathrm{dx} - \int_{\Gamma_{N_u}}g_0 u \mathrm{ds} + \int_{\Omega_2}(0.5c - c_0)c\mathrm{dx} -\Delta t\int_{\Omega_2}\frac{D}{2}\vert \nabla c \vert^2\mathrm{dx} + \Delta t\int_{\Gamma_{N_c}}g_2 c \mathrm{ds} + \lambda \Bigl( \kappa\nabla u \cdot \pmb{n} - FD\nabla c \cdot \pmb{n}\Bigr)\vert_{\partial\Omega_1\bigcup \partial \Omega_2}
$$
I would like to take the variation of $\mathcal{L}(u, c, \lambda)$, but I am unclear how to obtain the variation of the terms involving the Lagrange multiplier and would appreciate guidance on how to proceed.

What have you tried? If your proceed by computing the variational derivatives like in a standard problem you will eventually use Divergence Theorem which relates interior and boundary quantities.

I obtained the following variational form
$$
\delta \mathcal{L}(c, u, \lambda) = \int_{\Omega}\kappa \nabla u \cdot \nabla\delta u\mathrm{dx} - \int_{\Gamma_{N_u}}gu\mathrm{ds} +\int_{\Omega_2}(c-c_0)\delta c\mathrm{dx}  + \Delta t\int_{\Omega_2}D\nabla c \cdot \nabla \delta c \mathrm{dx}
- \Delta t\int_{\Gamma_X}g_2\delta c\mathrm{ds} + \delta\lambda \int_{\Gamma_X}\Bigl( \kappa\nabla u \cdot n - FD\nabla c \cdot n\Bigr)\mathrm{ds} + \int_{\Gamma_X}\frac{1}{\alpha}\lambda \delta\lambda\mathrm{ds}
$$
however, doesn't work for dynamic problem; only steady-state problem.

I should add that the above form is using perturbed Lagrangian to avoid zeros on diagonals.

What do you mean it “doesn’t work?” You differentiate the expression. Do you mean that your functional is incorrect and should contain some time derivatives? It is unclear what the objective is

My goal is to solve the Lagrangian obtained in FEA. I am not getting a correct approximation for the dynamic problem involving $c$. When I convert the problem to a steady-state remove the $(c-c0)\delta c$ terms and have $\Delta t$ = 1, then apply a Dirichlet bc on a subset of $\partial \Omega_2$, then I get the correct approximation. This is why I suspect my Lagrangian for the dynamic problem is incorrect.

Weak forms in finite elements and Lagrangians used in the calculus of variations are different things. Multiply the PDE by a test function then apply the appropriate integration theorems to obtain the weak form.

It isn't clear to me what your goal is. Is the goal to simulate the PDE using finite elements or is the goal to extremize some objective functional subject to the PDEs? One uses variational calculus and one does not.

The goal is to simulate the PDEs using finite element. The two pdes are coupled at the boundary $\partial\Omega_1\bigcup\partial\Omega_2$ (hence the constraint imposed by the Lagrange multiplier). Each of the PDEs multiplied by variation from same function space as solution gives the variational form and summing gives same expression as taking variation of Lagrangian. The flux from solution of $\nabla\cdot(\kappa u)=0$ at $\Omega_1\bigcup\Omega_2$ is the Neumann bc of $\frac{\partial t}{\partial t}-\nabla\cdot(D\nabla c)=0$ at $\Omega_1\bigcup\Omega_2$.

Here is how I would approach this problem. Begin by noticing that the system is actually triangular in that you can solve for $u$ everywhere then use that function to solve for $c$ alone. For this reason, we will set up two separate finite element problems as opposed to considering $(u,c)$ as an element of some product space.
Here we take $u\in H^1(\Omega_1\cup \Omega_2)$ and $v\in \mathcal{V} = H^1_0(\Omega_1\cup \Omega_2)$. The weak form is then
$$
\int_{\Omega_1 \cup \Omega_2} \kappa \nabla u\cdot \nabla v~\mathrm{d}x - \int_{\Gamma_{N_u}} g_0v~\mathrm{d}s = 0, \  \forall v\in\mathcal{V}, \\  \left. u \right|_{\Gamma_{D_u}} = f,
$$
where the Dirichlet condition is applied in the usual way of subtracting off some function $\tilde{u}$ that satifies it and and solving the resulting nonhomogeneous PDE with homogenenous Dirichlet BCs enforced in the function space.
We now consider a semidiscretization of $c$ where we keep it continuous in time. We take $c(t)\in H^1(\Omega_2)$ and test functions $w\in \mathcal{W} = H_0^1(\Omega_2)$. Let $\dot{c} = \frac{\partial c}{\partial t}$ and let $\Gamma_I = \partial \Omega_1 \cup \partial \Omega_2$. Then for all $t>0$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{\Omega_2} w \dot{c} - w\nabla\cdot(D\nabla c)~\mathrm{d}x &=0 \\
\int_{\Omega_2} w \dot{c} +  D\nabla w\cdot\nabla c~\mathrm{d}x - \int_{\partial \Omega_2} Dw\nabla c\cdot \boldsymbol{n}~\mathrm{d}s &=0 \\
\int_{\Omega_2} w \dot{c} +  D\nabla w\cdot\nabla c~\mathrm{d}x - \int_{\Gamma_I} \frac{\kappa}{F}w\nabla u\cdot \boldsymbol{n}~\mathrm{d}s &=0, \ \forall w\in\mathcal{W}, \ \forall t>0.
\end{aligned}
$$
Notice that in the last line we solved the interface flux condition for the $c$ flux and plugged it into the boundary integral. If we rearrange this final equation, we have
$$
\int_{\Omega_2} w \dot{c}~\mathrm{d}c = -\int_{\Omega_2}D\nabla w\cdot\nabla c~\mathrm{d}x + \int_{\Gamma_I} \frac{\kappa}{F}w\nabla u\cdot \boldsymbol{n}~\mathrm{d}s, \ \forall w\in\mathcal{W}, \ \forall t>0, \\ c(0) = c_0.
$$
Once a finite element discretization is chosen, we will obtain a finite-dimensional system of ODEs:
$$
\mathbf{M}\dot{\mathbf{c}} = \mathbf{K}\mathbf{c} + \mathbf{F}, \ t>0, \\ \mathbf{c}(0) = \mathbf{c_0}.
$$
We now apply any choice of time discretization we wish to perform the numerical integration. Notice that I have left the mass matrix $\mathbf{M}$ multiplying the LHS. Many time-stepping algorithms are designed to operate with this remaining on the LHS as inverting it or completing many linear solves can be very expensive and accurate time-stepping can be done without requiring this. Another advantage of this formulation is that you now no longer have to implement your own time-stepping routine. You can instead pass this to a purpose-built library for numerically solving ODEs which will likely have more sophisticated algorithms better-suited for large and stiff problems like these compared to what you could implement on your own.

Thank you. That's the correct approach for the problem I specified. I had however specified the less detailed version of the problem where Laplace's problem can be  solved first. The problem that I intend is such that $u$ is discontinuous at $\partial\Omega_1\bigcup\partial\Omega_2$ and I formulate that using symmetric interior penalty DG or HDG and it is such that the flux at that interface is a function of $[![ u ]!] - f(c)$. In this version, the system of equations is no longer triangular. That is why I'm looking for a formulation that solves the two coupled equations simultaneously.

I see. In that case, it may make more sense to split $u$ into two separate functions defined on the two subdomains with separate Poisson problems and a constraint on their values at the interface. I can write down the Lagrangian here in the comments later but I am not sure that completely specifies your problem. How is $u$ being discontinuous enforced? That seems like it may be overdetermining the Poisson problem, as $u$ should be uniquelly determined everywhere by the boundary values and $\kappa$

In DG and HDG, the field $u$ is solved for each cell. When the global system is assembled, penalty parameters are applied at dofs/facets to achieve continuity of $u$. Appropriate numerical traces are chosen to achieve conservativity and consistency. Because the assembly involves jumps of u $[![u]!]$ from integration over shared facets of adjacent cells, occurrences of $[![u]!]$ at $\partial\Omega_1\partial\Omega_2$ can be modified to reflect the flux expression there. I can't provide full equations in comment but see https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~arnold/papers/dgerr.pdf

I am familiar with DG methods, but I guess I don't understand how you can solve the Poisson equation over the combined domain with full boundary conditions while also imposing an internal flux/jump condition. My intuition says that you would be better off writing down more traditional weak forms for each of the equations then a separate interface constraint instead of combining them in a Lagrangian.

For context, I have solved the standalone Poisson problem in $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ and prescribed a flux expression at $\partial\Omega_1\bigcup\partial\Omega_2$ and the approximation makes sense. This flux expression determines the jump of $u$ over the shared boundary such that the larger the flux, the larger the jump. When that Poisson is coupled with the heat equation over $\Omega_2$ then the value of $c$ at $\partial\Omega_1\bigcup\partial\Omega_2$ decreases/increases magnitude of $[![u]!]$ for fixed flux. Let me make a new question with all the details and share link here.

Ok two Poisson problems with an interface condition that connects to a heat equation is very interesting and makes more sense to me.
